# split one big table to multi tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, performance

rails app, I have a table, the data already has hundreds of millions of records, I'm going to split the table to multiple tables, this can speed up the read and write.

I found this gem [octopus](https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus), but he is a master/slave, I just want to split the big table.

**or what can I do when the table too big?**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theoretically, a properly designed table with just the right indexes will be able to handle very large tables quite easily. As the table grows the slow down in queries and insertion of new records is supposed to be negligible. But in practice we find that it doesn't always work that way! However the solution definitely isn't to split the table into two. The solution is to [partition](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-overview.html).

> Partitioning takes this notion a step further, by enabling you to
>   distribute portions of individual tables across a file system
>   according to rules which you can set largely as needed. In effect,
>   different portions of a table are stored as separate tables in
>   different locations. The user-selected rule by which the division of
>   data is accomplished is known as a partitioning function, which in
>   MySQL can be the modulus, simple matching against a set of ranges or
>   value lists, an internal hashing function, or a linear hashing
>   function.

If you merely split a table your code is going to become inifinitely more complicated, each time you do an insert or a retrieval you need to figure out which split you should run that query on. When you use partitions, mysql takes care of that detail for you an as far as the application is concerned it's still one table.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an ID on each row? If the answer is yes, you could do something like:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id >= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1)/2);
```

The above statement creates a new table with half of the records from *table1*.

I don't know if you've already tried, but an index should help in speed for a big table.

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table1 (id)
```

*Note:* if you created the table using unique constraint or primary key, there's already an index.