# Random slowdown of queries on a MySQL innoDB table with 300mn rows and 50-100 queries per second

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization, innodb

I have a MySQL database with a single InnoDB table with about 300 million rows. There are up to 10 connected clients sending 50-60 read queries per second. Everything was smooth for a few months until recently, when MySQL started stalling, while using large amounts of CPU (100%+. `uptime` command shows values like 15, 12, 15.). Queries that would take 500ms now take several seconds, from tens to hundreds. Doing a `SHOW PROCESSLIST` shows queries hanging at the `Sending data` state.

I'm unable to figure out why and any help is appreciated.

### Server

Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5 @ 2.40GHz | 12 Cpus | 32 GB RAM

### my.cnf

```
innodb_file_per_table = 1
tmp-table-size                 = 32M
max-heap-table-size            = 32M
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-file-size           = 512M
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 26G
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 2
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb_file_format = barracuda
```

### Table (name: records)

```
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| identifier     | int(11)    | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
| timestamp      | int(11)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| rtype          | int(5)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| x1             | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| x2             | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| net            | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at     | datetime   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Indexed and used in the WHERE query:

- timestamp (UNIX timestamp as INT)
- identifier
- rtype (five possible
  values, 1-5)

### Data size

```
Data_length  = ~18 GB
Index_length = ~16 GB
```

### Query

```
SELECT identifier, timestamp, x1 AS a, x2 AS b, net
    FROM records
    WHERE
        identifier=1010
        AND timestamp >=1463111100
        AND timestamp <= 1463738400
        AND rtype=5
    ORDER BY timestamp;
```

(Returns about 900 rows. Sometimes completes in less than a second, sometimes 10-100s of seconds)

### Query analysis

```
select_type   = SIMPLE
type          = index_merge
possible_keys = indeXidentifier, indeXtimestamp, indeXrtype
key           = indeXidentifier, indeXrtype
key_len       = 4,5
rows          = 10641
Extra         = Using intersect(indeXidentifier,indeXrtype); Using where
```

Comment: That's quite a lot of data for 50 queries a second. It's possible that you are running into IO waits. In fact I am pretty sure this is the reason. One thing to consider is partitioning http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495085/split-one-big-table-to-multi-tables/37497045#37497045

Comment: @e4c5 Thanks. I'm going to try partitioning. Regarding IO waits, is it possible to diagnose them and get some numbers?

Comment: iostat on linux gives you this information for those who hate command line tools, newrelic has a nice chart

Comment: Do an iostsat with the current index and also with the index proposed in the answer

Comment: @e4c5 Tried both and the read rate was between 0.8 - 1 MBps and write rate was ~1.5 - 2 Mbps.

Comment: More interesting is the iowait column. If that's high, that means the one process has to wait for another process to finish reading or writing to the hard disk. Usully you see the iowait percentage is flat in most hard drives but after some point it climbs steeply

Answer (score 3):

I have two recommendation :

1 . Change the column order in your multi-column index.
Recommended order is: identifier, rtype, timestamp.

Index unique scan is faster than index range scan then it is better to appear first.

2 . Change your query like this:

```
select * from(
  SELECT identifier, timestamp, x1 AS a, x2 AS b, net
    FROM records
    WHERE
        identifier=1010
        AND timestamp >=1463111100
        AND timestamp <= 1463738400
        AND rtype=5
  ) t1 ORDER BY timestamp;
```

To avoid using index for sorting.

Comment: Thanks @Msf. Let me restructure the query and run it for a day. Sorry if the original post was ambiguous, but I don't have any composite or multi-column indices. identifier, rtype, and timestamp are indexed separately. Does the order still matter?

Comment: You're welcome. I think Multi-column index may solve your problem completely.

Comment: an (identifier, rtype) index makes sense. However, will making timestamp a part of it help? All the timestamp queries are >= <= ranges, and never an exact lookup.

Comment: In most situation Range scan index is very faster than no index. My intention in multi-column index was, it is better to place indexes in order that results more narrow records. My second recommendation in very occational situation can speed up queries.

Comment: removed the individual indices and added the multi-column ones as you suggested. Also tweaked the query to the one you suggested. The moment server is turned on (with around 10-20 queries per second), CPU goes through the roof.

Comment: Can you type here the query analysis (explain query) after changes you have made ?

Answer (score 1):

Either of these is optimal for the `SELECT` in the Question:

```
INDEX(rtype, identifier, timestamp)
INDEX(identifier, rtype, timestamp)
```

The principle is to put all the "= constant" parts of the `WHERE` first, then add one more thing on (the 'range' over `timestamp`).  [*More cookbook tips*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

There is no need to put this in a subquery -- that will only slow things down by building an unnecessary tmp table.

Why did it suddenly go slow?  The likely reason is "caching".  Right after adding the new index, less stuff was cached in RAM, and any `SELECTs` were hitting the disk a lot.

Let's double-check the query plan.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.  It should be one line long, indicate that it is using the 3-column index, and not say "intersect", "temporary", or "filesort".

If anything is still amiss, please provide that explain, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (It is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.)

Another thing to be sure to do:  Turn *off* the Query Cache.  Add/change these settings in `my.cnf` and restart the server:

```
query_cache_type = OFF
query_cache_size = 0
```

How are the `INSERTs` occurring?  One row at a time?  If they can be 'batching', even a few dozen at a time, that will help significantly.

Since you are commenting about CPU, it sounds like you have some query that is CPU-bound, not I/O-bound.  Do `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` -- do you see some query with a large "Time"?  Is it something you have not mentioned yet?

Please run

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections';
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Max_used_connections';
```

(The values may lead to a discussion of "thundering herds".)